# Two WebViews in same parent views don't work correctly

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa, webview

I have a frustrating issue I can't figure out.

I've built a Mac OS X app that has two WebViews in one parent view. The goal is to have two Fabric.io pages showing at the same time with live data one in the top half of the view, the other in the bottom.

If you know Fabric.io you know there's that live pulse of current active users, and their page's content is always updated live. Poking around their JS, it's done using web sockets.

Seems there's a network conflict when two WebViews occupy the same view because both views stop receiving the socket data and stop updating.

I did this in Swift and a version in Objective-C and they both have the same issue.

I'd add example code, but there's zero special happening here (probably part of the problem). For example, the Cocoa version literally is this:

```
[[FabricOne mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://fabric.io/login"]]];
[[FabricTwo mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://fabric.io/login"]]];
```

Someone asked a similar question two years ago but it was never answered, so I'm hoping I can resurrect this in my own question.

Comment: Can you share a description of what happens and any logs?

Comment: Just a thought, have you tried something something like adding a random "nothing string" to the end of the url i.e. http://..../login?makeMeUnique and to the other http://..../login?iHateUnique

Comment: Another thought.... NSSplitView with a fixed divider? Then they'll be childVIews of the NSSplitView rather than the NSView

Comment: Looks like the NSSplitView approach is working! Want to add it as an answer so I can mark it as such?

Comment: I take that back. Build worked all afternoon, when I relaunched it same issue. Very, very odd.